# Where do I get Med kits?

Tags: dark-meadow

The last patch claimed that a [bug was fixed](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dark-meadow/id511192872) and Health Kits would start spawning.

> -Fixed a bug where health packs were not spawning in world as they should

I've played through a few lives in the game after the update and still haven't gotten any med kits. They're not spawning in the open and I've opened the drawers/ect in a couple dozen rooms now, and killed lots of monsters and not a single med kit.

If it matters I'm playing the free version, but the update is for the free version and mentions they should spawn.

Where do I find med kits?

Comment: FWIW, I only found a handful of medkits dotted around. They seem to spawn very rarely (presumably to encourage players to purchase them)

Answer (score 1):

Try the recovery room. Also, they are on the wall and not in the drawers. You can only find money in the drawers.

Answer (score 0):

I always find a med kit in the record room on the first floor :3 hope this helped p.s. It's on the wall